# CSS (SASS) @font-face: Declared 3 fonts within font-family, only 2 are loaded

Tags: html, css, fonts, sass, font-face

I use `SASS` with version `3.2.9 (Media Mark)` and I want to use my custom `font-family` with 3 variants of the `Source Sans Pro` font (**Light**, **Regular**, **Bold**).

This is my `_font.scss` file:

```
// the charset to use
@charset "UTF-8";

// the relative path to the fonts directory
$sansSourceProPath: "../fonts/SourceSansPro" !default;

// the font-family
$default-font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';

/*
Light
*/
@font-face {
  font-family: #{$default-font-family};
  src: url('#{$sansSourceProPath}/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.eot');
  src: url('#{$sansSourceProPath}/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('#{$sansSourceProPath}/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
  url('#{$sansSourceProPath}/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('#{$sansSourceProPath}/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.svg#sourcesanspro-light') format('svg'); // EDITED
  font-weight: 300; // EDITED
  font-style: normal;
}

/*
Regular
*/
@font-face {
  font-family: #{$default-font-family};
  src: url('#{$sansSourceProPath}/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.eot');
  src: url('#{$sansSourceProPath}/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('#{$sansSourceProPath}/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
  url('#{$sansSourceProPath}/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.ttf'), format('truetype'),
  url('#{$sansSourceProPath}/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.svg#sourcesanspro-regular') format('svg'); // EDITED
  font-weight: 400; // EDITED
  font-style: normal;
}

/*
Bold
*/
@font-face {
  font-family: #{$default-font-family};
  src: url('#{$sansSourceProPath}/sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.eot');
  src: url('#{$sansSourceProPath}/sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('#{$sansSourceProPath}/sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
  url('#{$sansSourceProPath}/sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('#{$sansSourceProPath}/sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.svg#sourcesanspro-bold') format('svg'); // EDITED
  font-weight: 700; // EDITED
  font-style: normal;
}
```

In my `main.scss` file I declared the default font within the `html` tag like this:

```
html {
  font-size: $font-default-size; // 16px
  font-family: $default-font-family; // 'Source Sans Pro'
  font-weight: 300; // EDITED
}
```

and the element I use at my test page has the following CSS class:

```
.menu__header {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 400; // EDITED
    font-style: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Somehow, in latest `Google Chrome 30` only the **Light** and **Bold** fonts are loaded (requested). The needed **Regular** font is neither requested nor loaded (what confuses me as I haven't declared any element to use the **Bold** font and also only the **Light** font is shown)...

Am I doing something wrong?

**I updated the code so that it's not this confusing anymore - still it's only loading the *Light* and *Bold* fonts and never the *Regular* font...**

Answer (score 1):

Light is `font-weight: 300` not `200` (200 is extra light).  Why are you assigning the light font to the regular font-weight and the regular font to the bold, etc?  It's just going to make everything more confusing in the long run.

You can skip all of this and just add this before your closing `</head>` tag:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Your problem probably has to do with assigning the light face as regular, regular as bold, etc, especially considering that you did NOT make that change to the svg aliases, which means you're essentially mixing up the way you're using the variables.  If you are going to use light font-weight and font-face for your "normal" font weight (and regular for bold, etc) you need to do this consistently across all variables... but really you should just do it the normal way (regular is regular, light is light, bold is bold).

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply! the reason why I'm mixing things up like this is that I wanted to make it clear that the **Light** font is the **mainly used** font whereas the Regular and Bold fonts are just for headers, etc. - I'll turn things round and declare them like you suggested, and return with the results as soon as possible ;)

Comment: @herom Yeah I understand that type of thinking, but it just leads to this kind of confusion! Much better to simply apply global `font-weight: 300` styles (and `font-weight: 400` for `strong` and so forth).

Comment: I updated the code (added `// EDITED` comments to the lines which are changed) to make it less confusing as you suggested... still the client (browser) only loads the *Light* and *Bold* fonts, never the *Regular* font... :(

Comment: That's weird. You do have a typo in the bold weight svg line (`#souresanspro-bold` missing a c) but that obviously isn't the problem. So there is no `GET` request made for the regular weight font face at all in the network view?  Also, is there a specific reason you don't just include the webfont `link` directly from Google rather than hosting it locally?

Comment: No, there is never a `GET` request made - at least the Web Developer Toolbar isn't showing any request for this particular font (thanks for the typo hint). The specific reason why I'm not including it from Google is that this project is a web application which could also be used offline or behind a strict firewall which doesn't allow the user to access Google at all...

Comment: I use SASS every day but I just write the `@font-face` declarations manually so I can't help too much troubleshooting what's wrong. Maybe try changing the order? I know webfonts are weird about the order of `@font-face` rules - like they won't work properly as one `font-family` unless they are declared in specific order (regular, bold, italic, bold italic I think). Not sure where light falls into that but try commenting out one or both of the working ones or changing the order to see if that changes anything? Sorry I'm not more help!

Comment: Funny thing is, that IE (`v10` & `v11.0.9431.194`) is loading all 3 fonts as expected, but Chrome refuses to load it (just tested now) ...